# How to access the photos on an ios using Gluon

Tags: ios, javafx, gluon

I am developing a file sharing app and would like to access the Photos folder in the iphone. Is there a way to do this using Gluon.

Note: In android this was easy to implement using :
`File dcim  = Services.get(StorageService.class)
                     .map(s -> s.getPublicStorage("DCIM").get())
                     .orElseThrow(() -> new IOException("Error: DCIM not available"));`

Comment: Did you check the `PicturesService`? See [doc](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.5.0-SNAPSHOT/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/PicturesService.html#loadImageFromGallery--).

Comment: Yes, I tried the PicturesService loadImageFromGallery() method , but this allows to choose only one image and the method returns an Image object. Although this is a step forward, I want to select multiple images as image files.

Comment: I don't think you can access the gallery programmatically on iOS. Sharing files from there seems to be able only via `UIImagePickerController`, which is exactly what the `PicturesService` is doing. So you could work on this service, to handle the file instead of an image object, or allow selecting multiple files.